# Array.Sort / IComparable sometimes doesn't sort correctly on first call

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to solve [11321 - Sort! Sort!! and Sort!!!](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=2296) using C#, directly translating my solutions (as well as other people's) from cpp and Java.

My problem is that `listName.Sort()` or `Array.Sort(listName, ...Comparer.Create()...)` does not correctly sort the output during the first pass. I have to call it twice to be able to sort it properly.

In some cases, I manually set breakpoints inside the CompareTo() when calling Array.Sort, add a reference to the list inside the closure on purpose so I can watch the values as it sorts, and it sorts properly until after the Array.Sort() method returns, in which then I see some values return back to an incorrect order.

I am using [Morass' test cases from uDebug](https://www.udebug.com/UVa/11321) to test, and one example of an incorrect sort result I get is on line 10919 of the output:

```
Accepted            My Output
10919   457         10919   461
10920   461         10920   457
```

As you can see, the numbers 461 and 457 should be sorted in ascending order of their modulo 500 value, which is 461 and 457 respectively. If I call the sort method again a second time in my code below, then I finally get a correct output.

I guess my question is, why is this happening? Is there anything wrong with my implementation? My implementations are almost 1-to-1 translations of accepted Java or cpp code. Note that I've also tried using LINQ's OrderBy(), which produces different results but ultimately a correct one when called enough times.

I have the following Number class with the corresponding IComparable implementation:

```
class Number : IComparable<Number>
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public int Mod { get; }
    public bool IsOdd { get; }

    public Number(int val, int mod)
    {
        Value = val;
        Mod = mod;
        IsOdd = val % 2 != 0;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Number other)
    {
        var leftVal = Value;
        var leftMod = Mod;
        var rightVal = other.Value;
        var rightMod = other.Mod;

        var leftOdd = IsOdd;
        var rightOdd = other.IsOdd;

        if (leftMod < rightMod) return -1;
        else if (leftMod > rightMod) return 1;
        else
        {
            if (leftOdd && rightOdd)
            {
                return leftVal > rightVal ? -1 : 1;
            }
            else if (!leftOdd && !rightOdd)
            {
                return leftVal > rightVal ? 1 : -1;
            }
            else if (leftOdd)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else// (rightOdd)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var settings = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            var N = int.Parse(settings[0]);
            var M = int.Parse(settings[1]);

            if (N == 0 && M == 0) break;

            Console.WriteLine($"{N} {M}");
            var output = new List<Number>();

            var i = 0;
            while (i < N)
            {
                var line = Console.ReadLine();
                var val = int.Parse(line);
                var mod = val % M;
                output.Add(new Number(val, mod));
                i++;
            }

            output.Sort();
            // uncomment to produce acceptable answer
            // output.Sort();

            foreach (var line in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line.Value);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("0 0");
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

Just a note that I am redirecting stdin and stdout from a file/to a StringBuilder, so I can automate testing.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var output = new StringWriter(builder);
        Console.SetOut(output);

        var solution = File.ReadAllText("P11321_Outputs");
        var problem = new StreamReader("P11321_Inputs");
        Console.SetIn(problem);

        P11321_1.Main(args);
    }
```

**Edit 2:**
Here is a portion of the test case where the weird behavior is occurring. A concrete repro step is, if you change the test case to only have 38 items, and remove 11 from the input, then 457 and 461 sorts correctly.

Input:

```
39 500
-121
582
163
457
-86
-296
740
220
-867
-333
-773
11
-446
-259
-238
782
461
756
-474
-21
-358
593
548
-962
-411
45
-604
-977
47
-561
-647
926
578
516
382
-508
-781
-322
712
0 0
```

Output:

```
39 500
-977
-474
-962
-446
-411
-867
-358
-333
-322
-296
-781
-773
-259
-238
-647
-121
-604
-86
-561
-21
-508
11
516
45
47
548
578
582
593
163
712
220
740
756
782
382
926
457
461
0 0
```

Comment: This code sorts those 2 numbers correctly. I presume you are reading the larger input sample from a file? Post that code.

Comment: Yes. I am redirecting stdin and stdout from an input file and to a StringBuilder respectively so I can automate testing. I will post in a sec.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Manually tracing through paper, it sorts properly. A weird behavior I encountered was that, if I change the test case by adding or removing a few lines, then sometimes it sorts properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You managed to check all cases in your boolean tests, except for if the values are equal. A sort algorithm not only needs to know if elements are greater than or less than each other, it also needs to know if they are equal to each other.

```
  if (leftMod < rightMod)
    return -1;
  else if (leftMod > rightMod)
    return 1;
  else
  {
    if (leftVal == rightVal)
    {
      return 0; // need this so you don't orphan an element when tested against itself
    }
    if (leftOdd && rightOdd)
    {
      return leftVal > rightVal ? -1 : 1;
    }
    else if (!leftOdd && !rightOdd)
    {
      return leftVal > rightVal ? 1 : -1;
    }
    else if (leftOdd)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else// (rightOdd)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works, for some reason. Does Array.Sort compare elements to itself? Also, the erring test case was 457 and 461, which aren't equal and doesn't ever enter this added condition. How did this solve the problem, at least for the sample input?

Comment: Depending on the algorithm, it's not at all uncommon for a sort routine to compare an element to itself. Remember, a non-trivial sort routine moves elements around quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Doubling on Mark Benningfield's answer, I would like to present a proof of concept, about why including the equality in the implementation of a custom comparer is important. Not only there is a risk of incorrect results, but there is also a risk of never getting the results!

Trying to sort just two numbers (2, 1) with a buggy comparer:

```
class BuggyComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y) => x < y ? -1 : 1; // Equality?
}

var source = new int[] { 2, 1 };
var sorted = source.OrderBy(n => n, new BuggyComparer());
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", sorted)); // Infinite loop
```

The program is not terminating, because the sort cannot be completed.